# unix user alias

Tags: unix, user-management

is there a way to set up user aliases in unix such that if you have a user, `my_user`, they can log in with an alternate username, i.e. `my_user_alternate` and still be logged in as `my_user`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, create the new user and set its UID to be the same as the other one.

This is commonly used to create "alternate" root logins.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this by adding a new user with the same user id (uid) as the one you want as an alternative.

e.g.:

```
useradd -o -u 1001 my_user_alternate
```

It's the `-o` option that allows you to have the same uid. (Assuming that the user you want to 'copy' has a uid of 1020)

Comment: I'd also add `-g 1001` just to be safe and verbose.